Sharing Color Management Across Blender Installations
I use the environment variables BLENDER_USER_CONFIG and BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS so that any Blender installation on my computer shares the startup setup and add-on installation. Does anyone know if there's a way to define an environment variable or something similar so that the "colormanagement" folder inside "datafiles" is shared by all Blender installations, and I don't have to install ACES in all of them?

Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

I deleted the other post, it shouldn't exist because there were errors. That's why I have posted it again.

I am wondering how you found out about BLENDER_USER_CONFIG without having a look at the documentation. :D




Environment Variables





BLENDER_USER_RESOURCES:
Top level directory for user files. (other BLENDER_USER_* variables override when set).


BLENDER_USER_CONFIG:
Directory for user configuration files.


BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS:
Directory for user scripts.


BLENDER_USER_DATAFILES:
Directory for user data files (icons, translations, ..).


BLENDER_SYSTEM_RESOURCES:
Top level directory for system files. (other BLENDER_SYSTEM_* variables override when set).


BLENDER_SYSTEM_SCRIPTS:
Directory for system wide scripts.


BLENDER_SYSTEM_DATAFILES:
Directory for system wide data files.


BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON:
Directory for system Python libraries.


OCIO:
Path to override the OpenColorIO configuration file.


TEMP:
Store temporary files here (MS-Windows).


TMPDIR:
Store temporary files here (UNIX Systems). The path must reference an existing directory or it will be ignored.



Source: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#environment-variables
So you probably want to try OCIO, or just override all BLENDER_USER_RESOURCES. It seems colormanagement in user directory overrides the one in system directory at least in 4.1 so it should work if you just have everything in BLENDER_USER_RESOURCES(have not tested).

Thank you so, so much, Martynas.
